# Errors on my code are alerts, instead of console.errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm working on Vue.js project, and suddely errors than where errors on console, (console.error) are alerts, (normal browser alerts).

Example. I force this error writing `(undefined).anyProperty`

[image: Error on alert instead of console]

console looks:

[image: normal console]

My package.json modules:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "naranja": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
```

I cand debug in alerts, because objects are [Object object], thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Vue, but my recommendation for debugging this would be to replace the `window.alert` function with you own function containing a `debugger`

```
let oldWindowAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(){ 
  debugger; 
  oldWindowAlert.apply(window, arguments); 
}
```

Then, once you catch the debugger, you can investigate the call stack (in Chrome this is very easy) to trace down what function is emitting this alert.

Comment: I found with this solution, THANKS!!!!! : )

was an `addEventListener('error'` ... used for other dev

Comment: I knew it!  My answer was more correct, just seconds too late :-P ..... @mistahenry - great idea for finding the offending call, tho :-)

Answer (score 1):

So I did a bit of research for you, but haven't actually tested my hypothesis so take this with a grain of salt...

My gut tells me that somewhere in the code there is an event handler attached to the window error event which alerts the error message and swallows the error.  Search the codebase for `addEventHandler('error'`, `addEventHandler("error"`, and `onerror`, and get rid of it :-)

Comment: Stringify all of the console logs, or comment out all except one - and stringify that one.

Comment: Indeed I did. You still found it!

Comment: To be fair it was a direct response to my answer, so stackoverflow alerted me to it :-P

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier) lead me to believe that Node_Notifier is the culprit. Hard to tell without seeing your code but maybe see what happens if you remove it?

Comment: node-notifier is used for launch native notifications about vue-cli compilation, checking for source has nothing about browser alerts, [check here](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/search?q=alert&unscoped_q=alert)

Comment: This line seems to imply that it is configured to produce alerts.    
   `<key>NSUserNotificationAlertStyle</key>
 <string>alert</string>`

Comment: It's a info.plist configuration, for launch native notification on macOS, I'm working on windows

Comment: I'd be curious to look at the code.  In the meantime if you  `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject)) you should at least be able to see the object.

Comment: His problem is that he doesn't necessarily know where the error is happening, so how can he log the offending object?

Comment: Solved, another dev left the code by accident an `addEventListener ('error' ... alert`